# Does React.js has similar modifier like Vue.js "v-model.lazy"

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

In Vue.js :

By default, v-model syncs the input with the data after each input event (with the exception of IME composition as stated above). You can add the lazy modifier to instead sync after change events:

```
<!-- synced after "change" instead of "input" -->
<input v-model.lazy="msg" >
```

Does react has the similar modifier or function?In which part of the official doc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is from Vue docs for `v-model`:

> Although a bit magical, v-model is essentially syntax sugar for
>   updating data on user input events

In React, you can listen to any input event ( `onChange`, `onClick`, etc. ) and trigger a function that updates the React Component's `state`. If you want to pass the data down, you can pass it as `props` to any children. In this way we can keep data updated with input events. For more info, see [React State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and [React Component and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Is there an equivalent *syntax sugar* for React for binding an input to a state variable?

Answer (score 7):

**onChange** (in React) will do exactly what v-model do in VueJS.

Vue `<input type="text" v-model="record" />`

React `<input type="text" name="record" onChange={e => setRecord(e.target.value)} />`

You can use **onBlur** event on input field in order to achieve functionality similar to v-model.lazy in VueJS.

Vue `<input type="text" v-model.lazy="record" />`

React `<input type="text" name="record" onBlur={e => setRecord(e.target.value)} />`

Answer (score 4):

The [.lazy modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy) in Vue.js will sync on DOM's change events instead of input. DOM's change events occur in a variety of situations depending on the form element used. A check box or radio button will trigger a change event when it’s clicked. An input text box will trigger a change event when it loses focus. Different browsers might not trigger change events on the same interactions.

However, React's onChange works differently than onChange in the DOM: it’s more like DOM's onInput. React's onChange fires when there is a change in any of the form’s input elements, in contrast to the DOM’s change event.

In React.js, if you'd like to have the similar behaviour as Vue.js' `v-model.lazy`, you need to bind the event handler to a different event.

In regard to your example, in Vue.js we have:

```
<!-- synced after "change" instead of "input" -->
<input v-model.lazy="msg" >
```

In React.js, we cannot use onChange, as the onChange handler is fired on every key stroke, not just when the whole input field has changed. React.js' onChange is not "lazy" :-) Instead, you can use its [onBlur](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#focus-events) event:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      msg: ''
    }
  }
  handleBlur(event) {
    this.setState({msg: event.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <input type="text" onBlur={this.handleBlur.bind(this)}/>
      <p>Your message: {this.state.msg}</p>
    </div>
  }
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jyougo/x9sL245r/)'s the example on jsfiddle.

Comment: onBlur works well if you are on "add" mode, but in "edit" mode, if you want to populate the textfield value with the current value to edit it, it will not working because you can't use value props if you are using onBlur. I don't know if a solution exist